# Find common point of $C_f$ and y=x

Tags: functions

I am stack on the following question.

Let $f:R->R$  be a function such that 
$f(f(x))=x^2-3x+4$ for all real x.
Find the common points of $C_f$ and line $y=x$. ($C_f$ is the graph of the function.)

I have proved that there can't be any negative x's and thus we search on $(0,+\infty)$ where we can prove $f$ is bijective. but i can't make any more progress.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $(x,y)$ is a common point of $C_f$ and the line $y=x$, then $x=y=f(x)$, hence $x=f(x)=f(f(x))=x^2-3x+4$.

Your turn !

Comment: Hmm Doesnt that only prove that only 2 can be the answer?
How are we going to prove that $f(2)=2$.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Thank You!.